# Ignore asterisk when importing excel into C# datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, sql-server-2012

I have a C# script that reads an excel file into a datatable and then populates a database table which contains X number of columns all of data type varchar. The image below compares the excel data source to the imported version on the database. This is how I need it to work, note the level of precision.

[image]

However, there is occasionally asterisks in the data source to suppress low figures. This has the following effect on the import. Note the change of lack of precision in Col3.

[image]

I imagine this is due to my script seeing multiple datatypes in Col3 and converting it to a varchar when populating the datatable. This is currently being handled using `IMEX=1` in my connection string.

Is there a way I manipulate my code so it will convert any asterisk to an easily identifiable value such as -999 without modifying the datasource in excel?

Here is my code

```
String FilePath = "Code to get file path";
String SheetName = "Code to get sheet name";
String SheetRange = "Code to get sheet range";

SourceConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO'";

OleDbConnection SourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(SourceConnectionString);

String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "$" + SheetRange + "]";

OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, SourceConnection);

DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(myCommand);

myDataAdaptor.Fill(myDataTable);
```

Comment: IMEX = 1 in the connection string is treating the data like text. Are you saying the data is still not precise once the DataTable is filled with this attribute in the conn string?

Comment: The only time the data is not precise enough is when an asterisk or non numeric character appears in that column, it affects all data in that column. I would like the level of precision to be the same as the other columns and asterisks to be replaced by the number -999.

Comment: Is the data precise in the Excel document you are connecting to? The code is connecting to the Excel document; if the data is not precise therein and you cannot augment the Excel document then the process that populates the Excel from the database would need altered.

Comment: Yes it is precise enough in excel, it is just displayed to 0 decimal places. It appears as though when the C# sees there is an asterisk in the column it ignores the extra data and just inserts the value to 0 decimal places.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot reproduce the issue. The values in the column with the asterisk retain their precision when I view them in the DataTable. I used a wholly new Excel (format unchanged) with values in Column A, Rows 1-3 of: 0.1234567, *, 7654321.01234

Comment: Would you be able to try it with the cells as percent format instead of general.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113054/discussion-between-simon-tindall-and-ryan-peters).